# ELEMENT not found in webdriver, but works in IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I can successfully run the following script in selenium IDE but webdriver can find the first element. I m using HP WebTours App in localhost. Its a simple script.At first I thought perhaps the script runs faster but putting an implicit or explicit wait didnt solve the problem.

```
public void testLoginWtour() throws Exception {
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,5); //this is explicit wait
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.name("username")) ));

        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("jojo");
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("bean");
        driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click(); 
}
```

Comment: Did you check how IDE found the item?
I mean via ID,Name,Css or any other identifier If you didn't please do and try to use the same identifier in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `"userName"` instead of `"username"`

Here is the HTML

```
<input type="text" name="userName" size="10">
```

You don't need any explicit waits. Just change it to `"userName"`

```
driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys("jojo");
```

Below is the image from IDE as well. It is capturing as "userName"

[image]

Comment: this is how the IDE itself found  -   name=username

Comment: are you sure? I just recorded the same using IDE and it is showing as "userName" only. I have edited the answer to include IDE screenshot as well.

Comment: yup, u r right, how on earth did I skip that but I found that problem was not limited to the element name, nevertheless ,I m accepting ur answer. Thanks a lot.